# How to run follower demo using voice control demo?

Tags: ros, turtlebot, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I try Turtlebot Voice Control Demo, and it worked . Now I want to add new voice instruction, so I add this instructions in nav_command.txt and upload it to [Sphinx Knowledge Base Tool](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html)
I finish this step successfully
Now I have to modify on voic_nav.py which map the voice instruction into robot action
If I want to say "come with me" so this voice instruction make robot run follower demo !

any one have idea how to do this !

Thanks in Advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65042/how-to-run-follower-demo-using-voice-control-demo-?/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  sounds a funny idea.

You can use the app_manager to start/stop/lists apps in the robot. Assuming you launched turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch, you can list the available apps with:

```
rosservice call /turtlebot/list_apps | grep -v data
```

(the grep is to avoid get spammed with icons binary data)

To start/stop follower:

```
rosservice call /turtlebot/start_app "name: 'turtlebot_core_apps/follower'"
rosservice call /turtlebot/stop_app "name: 'turtlebot_core_apps/follower'"
```

Note that start the app takes some time, as it launches opennni driver and some other stuff. Once started, following behavior can be activated/deactivated with:

```
rosservice call /turtlebot_follower/change_state "state: 1"
rosservice call /turtlebot_follower/change_state "state: 0"
```

This is much faster and less error prone that start/stop the app. Btw, you can also call services with the service client API.

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-06-18**:
I want to start robot follower using voice control

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-06-18**:
Yep, in your voice recognition system you can call the above mentioned services. I'm not familiar with Sphinx, but I suppose you have some kind of callbacks in your program when it recognizes a command.